# How to apply Excel formula to a dataframe with first row blocked

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to apply a formula to my dataframe columns B and C that would be equivalent of excel B2*100/$B$2 and C2 * 100/$C$2 and dragging down.

Input

```
Date    B      C
1/20   0.1    0.2
2/20   0.05    0.3
3/20  -0.1    -0.05
```

Desired Outcome

```
Date    B      C
1/20   100    100
2/20   50     150
3/20  -100    -25
```

Thank you

Comment: what have you tried and I think you mean `B3=B3*100/$B$2`?

Comment: I tried some for loops but didn't work. By B2 I meant  cell with 0.1 and by C2 I meant cell with 0.2

Comment: Excel equivalent formula would be: `df.B * 100 / df.B[0]`, same for `C`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['B'] = df['B'].multiply(100).div(df['B'].iloc[0])
df['C'] = df['C'].multiply(100).div(df['C'].iloc[0])
```

Note that dataframe indexes start at 0, not 1, and headers do not count, so the second row of you spreadsheet has the index of 0 in the dataframe.

Comment: that is incorrect. You need `.iloc[0]` not `.iloc[1]`

Comment: I realized that after the comment was posted by the author. Now fixed after edit.